# The configuration is invalid Error for SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net, simple-injector

### Error Message:

The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type UserController failed. The registered delegate for type UserController threw an exception. The registered delegate for type IApplicationDatabaseFactory returned null.

I have two databases, I am using Entity Framework.

Here is the link to the code: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=738F28AF693709DC!388&authkey=!ALw3VMi6GEaiTZg&ithint=file%2c.zip

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=738F28AF693709DC!391&authkey=!AJZ2fPbU7CBctYw&ithint=folder%2c

I need help in configuring the SimpleInjector.

There are two databases 1.SWT DB 2. Authorization DB
The SWT DB has RegionRepository 
Auth DB has UserRepository.
They both have CommandHandlers in the constructors, which take the DBInstance. SimpleInjector has to be configured to pass the right instance of the DB to the repositories.

This is the Global.ascx code where the configuration is happening, need help in configuring the simpleInjector here in Application_Start()

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {

        var container = new Container();

        var services = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services;
        var controllerTypes = services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver()
            .GetControllerTypes(services.GetAssembliesResolver());

        foreach (var controllerType in controllerTypes)
        {
            container.Register(controllerType);
        }

        container.RegisterAll<DbContext>(typeof(SWDMSEntities), typeof(TicketingDBEntities));

        container.Register<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>(() => new AuthorizationDatabaseFactory(new SWDMSEntities()), Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ISWTDatabaseFactory>(() => new SWTDatabaseFactory(new TicketingDBEntities()), Lifestyle.Singleton);

        //container.RegisterAll<IApplicationDatabaseFactory>(typeof(AuthorizationDatabaseFactory), typeof(SWTDatabaseFactory));

        //registering 
        ////container.RegisterAll<IEntityCommand>(typeof(AddEntityCommand), typeof(DeleteEntityCommand));


        //// Register the command handler
        container.Register<ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand>, AddEntityCommandHandler>();
        container.Register<ICommandHandler<UpdateEntityCommand>, UpdateEntityCommandHandler>();
        container.Register<ICommandHandler<DeleteEntityCommand>, DeleteEntityCommandHandler>();

        //// Go look in all assemblies and register all implementations
        //// of ICommandHandler<T> by their closed interface:

        ////container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
        ////    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
        ////    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);

        // Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with
        // a InfoLoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
        container.RegisterDecorator(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            typeof(InfoLoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

        // Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with
        // a AuthorizationCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
        container.RegisterDecorator(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            typeof(AuthorizationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));


        var lifestyle = new LifetimeScopeLifestyle();

        var Authdb = new InstanceProducer(typeof(IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory),
                lifestyle.CreateRegistration<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>(
                () => new AuthorizationDatabaseFactory(new SWDMSEntities()), container));

        var Appdb = new InstanceProducer(typeof(ISWTDatabaseFactory),
                lifestyle.CreateRegistration<ISWTDatabaseFactory>(
                () => new SWTDatabaseFactory(new TicketingDBEntities()), container));


        container.RegisterWithContext<IApplicationDatabaseFactory>(context =>
        {
            Type commandType = context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

            if (context.ImplementationType == typeof(IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory))
            {
                return container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>();
                //return (IApplicationDatabaseFactory)Authdb.GetInstance();
            }
            else if (context.ImplementationType == typeof(ISWTDatabaseFactory))
            {
                return container.GetInstance<ISWTDatabaseFactory>();
                // return (IApplicationDatabaseFactory)Appdb.GetInstance();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        });       


        //// Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        container.Register<IRegionRepository, RegionRepository>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

        // Verify the container configuration
        container.Verify();

        // Register the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

Here are the Interfaces and classes

```
 public interface IApplicationDatabaseFactory :
    IDisposable
{
    DbContext GetContext();
}

public interface ISWTDatabaseFactory :
    IApplicationDatabaseFactory
{
}

 public interface IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory :
    IApplicationDatabaseFactory
{
}

 public abstract class ApplicationDatabaseFactoryBase :
    IApplicationDatabaseFactory
{
    private DbContext dataContext;
    private bool isDisposed;
    public ApplicationDatabaseFactoryBase(DbContext dBContext)
    {
        dBContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  ////Do not remove these lines as they are required
        dBContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; ////Do not remove these lines as they are required
        this.dataContext = dBContext;
    }

    ~ApplicationDatabaseFactoryBase()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public DbContext GetContext()
    {
        return this.dataContext;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (this.dataContext != null)
        {
            this.dataContext.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.isDisposed && disposing)
        {
            this.DisposeCore();
        }

        this.isDisposed = true;
    }
}

public class SWTDatabaseFactory :
    ApplicationDatabaseFactoryBase,
    ISWTDatabaseFactory
{
    public SWTDatabaseFactory( TicketingDBEntities  dBContext) :
        base((DbContext)dBContext)
    {
    }

    ~SWTDatabaseFactory()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}

 public class AuthorizationDatabaseFactory : 
    ApplicationDatabaseFactoryBase,
    IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory
{       
    public AuthorizationDatabaseFactory(SWDMSEntities dbContext) :
        base((DbContext)dbContext)
    {
    }

    ~AuthorizationDatabaseFactory()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IRegionRepository :
    IRepository<Region>
{
}

 public class RegionRepository :
    RepositoryBase<Region>,
    IRegionRepository
{
    public RegionRepository(
        ISWTDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
        ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand> addEntityCommandHandler,
        ICommandHandler<UpdateEntityCommand> updateEntityCommandHandler,
        ICommandHandler<DeleteEntityCommand> deleteEntityCommandHandler)
        : base((IApplicationDatabaseFactory)databaseFactory, addEntityCommandHandler, updateEntityCommandHandler, deleteEntityCommandHandler)
    {
    }
}

 public interface IUserRepository :
   IRepository<Authorization_User>
{        
}

 public class UserRepository :
    RepositoryBase<Authorization_User>,
    IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(
        IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
        ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand> addEntityCommandHandler,
        ICommandHandler<UpdateEntityCommand> updateEntityCommandHandler,
        ICommandHandler<DeleteEntityCommand> deleteEntityCommandHandler)
        : base(databaseFactory, addEntityCommandHandler, updateEntityCommandHandler, deleteEntityCommandHandler)
    {
    }
}

 public class AddEntityCommandHandler : 
    EntityCommandHandlerBase,
    ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand>
{
    public AddEntityCommandHandler(IApplicationDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) :
        base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }
    public Execute(AddEntityCommand addEntityCommand)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code..!!!

Comment: Plesse Don't put it on pastbin. Add the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem to your question. Add the exact exception message and possibly a stack trace.  Without this information it's impossible for us to answer the question, and your question will be put on hold rather quickly.

Comment: Added a link to the source code, to the original post

Comment: So you pointed us at a 70 MB big .zip file with 13 projects and over 120 .cs classes in it without even saying where to look? Don't forget that visitors of Stackoverflow spend their free time in helping other developers. You should pay some respect to that by coming up with a good focused question that shows the actual code and pinpoints the problem. We love to help you, but I suggest you [read this first](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and ask a new question after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've coded `null` as a return type of `IApplicationDatabaseFactory`

```
container.RegisterWithContext<IApplicationDatabaseFactory>(context =>
{
    Type commandType = context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

    if (context.ImplementationType == typeof(IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>();
    }
    else if (context.ImplementationType == typeof(ISWTDatabaseFactory))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<ISWTDatabaseFactory>();
    }
    else
    {
        // see here
        return null;
    }
});
```

---

I also don't think `context.ImplementationType == typeof(IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory)` will ever be true. Try something like this:

```
container.RegisterWithContext<IApplicationDatabaseFactory>(context =>
{
    if (typeof(IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory)
        .IsAssignableFrom(context.ImplementationType))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>();
    }
    else if (typeof(ISWTDatabaseFactory)
        .IsAssignableFrom(context.ImplementationType))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<ISWTDatabaseFactory>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
});
```

---

Ok, I can see what `commandType` was for now - you will want something like the code below which is attempting to return the `IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory` for an `ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand>`

```
container.RegisterWithContext<IApplicationDatabaseFactory>(context =>
{
    Type commandType = context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

    if (commandType == typeof(AddEntityCommand))
    {
        return container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
});
```

Comment: IApplicationDatabaseFactory should never be called as there is no concrete class which is implementing it.  The two implementations are for IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory and ISWTDatabaseFactory, they inturn inherit IApplicationDatabaseFactory which has common stuff.  Each implementation points to separate DBs. Even Without "NULL" the application configuration was still invalid.

Comment: @Kish_ore I wonder if `context` is not what you are expecting. Have you tried capturing the values for `context.ImplementationType.GetType()`. This code snippet is odd for a couple of reasons - 1) it defines `commandType` that is not used 2) it is referring to `context.ImplementationType == typeof(xxx)`, should it be using `IsAssignableFrom()` as implementations are `classes` not `interfaces`?

Comment: The context.ImplementationType I am getting is of type ICommandHandler<AddEntityCommand> as you can see from the example the AddEntityCommandHandler implemts the ICommandHandler and its constructor has IApplicationDatabaseFactory,  This value IApplicationDatabaseFactory is null, and that throws an exception.
The idea is to reslove the IApplicationDatabaseFactory to a concrete DatabaseFactory and pass it in the constructor based on the correct context of Repositiory.

Comment: @Kish_ore let me know how you get on with the update I just made

Comment: This configuration works fine, I did not get any compilation error, but I always get IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory instance rather than getting context based instance of IAuthorizationDatabaseFactory or ISWTDatabaseFactory for the CommandHandler Object.
I based my implementation of CommandHandlers on this article: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91

Comment: @Kish_ore that's a great start for any system ;-). Going forward you'll need to either extend `container.RegisterWithContext<IApplicationDatabaseFactory` for your types or not bother with this at all and let each Command Handler explicitly state which implementation you want. i.e. do away with `IApplicationDatabaseFactory` and each handler says which one it wants? Just a suggestion. Glad you got your stuff working now.